# Smoothest Remote Desktop protocol

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, nomachine

I would like to remote desktop from my iPad to several Windows and Ubuntu machines. Which protocol do you suggest? (Of course) I want the least latency, best picture, and lag free experience. I've tried the built in VNC protocol, RDP (which seems somewhat okay) and NoMachine (which is kinda good, but has lots of compression). Just wanted to see if I missed some, since I've been searching everywhere.

Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: Network connection speed between the machines is a huge factor.  Don't forget to consider that.

Comment: That won't be a problem. That has been taken care of. :)

Comment: Since you specifically mentioned "least latency, best picture, and lag free experience" it didn't really sound like it.  Those are all issues created by slower network hardware.

Comment: Agree with @Tyson on this - RDP (I don't know the internals of the others) will do a lot of adjustments based on network characteristics (e.g.: change compression algorithms). Other factor to consider (for RDP) is the protocol version supported on the server side (latest version is Win10)-newer versions have more features. Last but not least, depending on the hardware, RDP automatically enables RemoteFX which leverages your GPU (graphics card) to encode data ( https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rds/2013/10/21/microsoft-remote-desktop-apps-for-ios-mac-os-x-and-android-available-for-download/ )

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you Google 'remote desktop linux and windows' Don't know what you mean by 'lots of compression'. I have tried most of the available solutions out there, and there are probably around 30 different products. The only ones that stand out for pure cross-platform and outstanding performance are NoMachine and possibly Splashtop.